# DBMS: How to get the creation date of a column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Example:

If a column got added in the table much after the table was created.
Where does the Data/Time information of it gets stored?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server does not keep track of specific changes to tables. If you want or need this level of detail, you need to create a DDL Trigger (introduced in SQL Server 2005) that can trap certain specific events or even classes of events, and log those changes to a history table that you create.

DDL Triggers are "after" triggers; there is no "instead of" option. However, if you want to disallow an action, you can just issue a `ROLLBACK` and that will cancel what happened.

The MSDN page for [DDL Triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175941.aspx) has a lot of good information regarding how to trap either specific events (i.e. `ALTER TABLE`) and using the `EVENTDATA` function, which returns XML, to get the specifics of what event fired the trigger, including the exact SQL query that was executed. In fact, the MSDN page for [Use the EVENTDATA Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187909.aspx) even has simple examples of creating a DDL trigger to capture `ALTER TABLE` statements (in the "
ALTER TABLE and ALTER DATABASE Events" section) and creating a DDL trigger to capture the events to a log table (in the "Example" section). Since all `ALTER TABLE` commands will fire this trigger, you need to parse out which ones are specific to what you are looking for. And, maybe now that you know that this is an option, capturing more than just adding columns is desired (i.e. dropping columns, changing the datatype and/or NULLability, etc).

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server still does not have any system views that allow you to see the create/modify date at a column level. You will have to see the modify_date column of a table.

This might help you if in your case the change made was recent one. But if any more changes have been made on the table, it will start reflecting the date of the most recent change.

```
select name, modify_date from sys.objects where name=@table_name
```